# Fill text fields in WebView online form without id's

Tags: java, javascript, android

Im trying to make a program to fill out an online login using local string variables.
Here is what i have so far:

```
        web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = web.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 " +
                "(Windows NT 6.2; " +
                "WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 " +
                "(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20 " +
                "Safari/537.31");
        web.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.CLOSE);
        web.loadUrl("http://ta.yrdsb.ca/yrdsb/");

        web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
           public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
              String username="test";
              String password="test";
              view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('username').value = '"+username+"';document.getElementById('password').value='"+password+"';");
           }
        });
```

My problem is that the fields are not being filled in. I think the issue is with the id's, because from what i can see, it seems that the text fields on this particular site do not have an id associated with them. This is what the username field is (there is no id):

```
<input type="text" name="username" size="10" border="0">
```

So my question is how would i go about doing this without having the ids of the username and password fields, or am i just missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dont have any ID's you can do this:

```
document.getElementsByName("username")[0].value = "username";
```

You are currently requresting by ID but there is'nt any ID on the element.

Comment: hey . can you please refer to any full example. I have not worked with this kind of code before .